# weird behaviour --- Popup modal showing white border grid in background images onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem with a modal on my  [Testbed Website](https://parlous-morals.000webhostapp.com/)

The problem:

When clicking the image "gamers blade chair, the first one is where i applied the test modal code" it opens the modal but shows white borders on the gallery images in the background, see: [image: HERE]

i do not know what is causing it so that is why i am here

here is the css code: [CSS](https://parlous-morals.000webhostapp.com/css/style.css)

here is the modal CSS code:

```
/* modal */


/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg1:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal1 {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content1 {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}


/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content1{
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px){
  .modal-content1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* endmodal*/
```

Thank you in foward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part of your code:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal1 {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */ --------------------------> It's not enough because '.product-card:before' has the same value
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
```

You set the z-index: 1, if you change to z-index: 2 will solve your problem.

Check the documentation in order to understand better about your problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index